# Why does my "cube" not unwrap into a T

Tags: uv

Originally, I had my layout like this in Blender:

[image]

The gaps are placed there by hand so that bleeding in photoshop wasn't so hard to sort out.

I then made some changes and wanted to get back to the T shape, but when i do the following cuts:

[image]

I get this:

[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: maybe you've ripped an edge? in that case select all in Edit mode, Alt M to merge by distance, then unwrap again?

Comment: That was it! Crikey! No idea when I did that. Thanks moonboots. you legend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've ripped an edge, select all in *Edit* mode, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to merge by distance, then unwrap again.